# Specifying precedence for __matmul__ operations?

Tags: python

Is there a good pattern for changing precedence of @ operation? (perhaps something along the lines of numpy's `__array_priority__`?).

IE, if `a` is an instance of `LowLevel` and A is an instance of `HighLevel`, I want HighLevel `__matmul__` to be called first.

`a @ a @ A @ A @ A @ a`  evaluating in order `(a @ a) @ (((A @ A) @ A) @ a)`

```
A@A  # highest priority
A@a  # lower priority
a@a  # lowest priority
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811051/change-operator-precedence-in-python